# selenium find element that has no name, no id and no unique class

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape a site that has several tabs on can click on it but each clickable tab has no unique id, name or class.

The tab portion of the site looks very much like this:

[image]

And the HTML, unordered list, containing them is coded in the site as follows:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    </li><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><li ng-class="{active: active, disabled: disabled}" ng-repeat="tab in tabState.tabs" heading="Movies" active="tab.active" select="select(tab)" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
        <a href="" ng-click="select()" uib-tab-heading-transclude="" class="ng-binding">Movies</a>
    </li><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><li ng-class="{active: active, disabled: disabled}" ng-repeat="tab in tabState.tabs" heading="Music" active="tab.active" select="select(tab)" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope active">
        <a href="" ng-click="select()" uib-tab-heading-transclude="" class="ng-binding">Music</a>
    </li><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><li ng-class="{active: active, disabled: disabled}" ng-repeat="tab in tabState.tabs" heading="Books" active="tab.active" select="select(tab)" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
        <a href="" ng-click="select()" uib-tab-heading-transclude="" class="ng-binding">Books</a>
    </li><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><li ng-class="{active: active, disabled: disabled}" ng-repeat="tab in tabState.tabs" heading="Magazines" active="tab.active" select="select(tab)" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
        <a href="" ng-click="select()" uib-tab-heading-transclude="" class="ng-binding">Magazines</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How would I click on the desired tab using python/selenium?  Let us imagine the desired tab is MUSIC.

I tried something like this:

```
myEl = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[class='ng-binding']")
```

But how do i know which of the classes is selecting, since Movies, music, books and magazines are all of class='ng-binding'

Answer (score 3):

please try below code:

```
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Movies")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all those elements with that selector and loop through them & make a selection based on the text.

```
allTabs = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[class='ng-binding']")

for tab in allTabs:
    if tab.text == 'Movies':
        tab.click()   #Or do something else with it    
        break;
```

Comment: how do I know from  this selection if it's selecting the movies, music, books or magazines tab?

Comment: Look at the class attribute all four elements, only one has the text `active` in it.

Comment: that's just in the example.  For more generality let us say i want Books, that one doesn't have the text active, what'd i do in that case?  Ideally the only unique ID is in the tab name MOVIES, MUSIC, etc.  But I have no idea how to select based on that

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. I updated the answer, is that close to what you are looking for?